# Bigquery internalError when streaming data

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm getting the following error while streaming data:

```
 Google.ApisGoogle.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Internal Error [500]
Errors [
    Message[Internal Error] Location[ - ] Reason[internalError] Domain[global]
]
```

My code:

```
public bool InsertAll(BigqueryService s, String datasetId, String tableId, List<TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData> data)
{
    try
    {
        TabledataResource t = s.Tabledata;
        TableDataInsertAllRequest req = new TableDataInsertAllRequest()
        {
            Kind = "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
            Rows = data
        };
        TableDataInsertAllResponse response = t.InsertAll(req, projectId, datasetId, tableId).Execute();
        if (response.InsertErrors != null)
        {  
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm streaming data constantly and many times a day I have this error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

We seen several problems:

- the request randomly fails with type 'Backend error'
- the request randomly fails with type 'Connection error'
- the request randomly fails with type 'timeout' (watch out here, as only some rows are failing and not the whole payload)
- some other error messages are non descriptive, and they are so vague that they don't help you, just retry.
- we see hundreds of such failures each day, so they are pretty much constant, and not related to Cloud health.

For all these we opened cases in paid Google Enterprise Support, but unfortunately they didn't resolved it. It seams **the recommended option to take is an exponential-backoff with retry**, even the support told to do so. Also the failure rate fits the 99.9% uptime we have in the SLA, so there is no reason for objection.

There's something to keep in mind in regards to the SLA, it's a very strictly defined structure, the details are [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla). The 99.9% is uptime not directly translated into fail rate. What this means is that if BQ has a 30 minute downtime one month, and then you do 10,000 inserts within that period but didn't do any inserts in other times of the month, it will cause the numbers to be skewered. This is why we suggest a exponential backoff algorithm. The SLA is explicitly based on uptime and not error rate, but logically the two correlates closely if you do streaming inserts throughout the month at different times with backoff-retry setup. Technically, you should experience on average about 1/1000 failed insert if you are doing inserts through out the month if you have setup the proper retry mechanism.

You can check out this chart about your project health:
https://console.developers.google.com/project/YOUR-APP-ID/apiui/apiview/bigquery?tabId=usage&duration=P1D

---

About times. Since streaming has a limited payload size, see [Quota policy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) it's easier to talk about times, as the payload is limited in the same way to both of us, but I will mention other side effects too.

We measure between 1200-2500 ms for each streaming request, and this was consistent over the last month as you can see in the chart.

[image]

---

The approach you've chosen if takes hours that  means `it does not scale`, and won't scale. You need to rethink the approach with `async processes` that can retry.

Processing in background IO bound or cpu bound tasks is now a common practice in most web applications. There's plenty of software to help build background jobs, some based on a messaging system like [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/).

Basically, you needed to distribute insert jobs across a closed network, to prioritize them, and consume(run) them. Well, that's exactly what Beanstalkd provides.

Beanstalkd gives the possibility to organize jobs in tubes, each tube corresponding to a job type.

You need an API/producer which can put jobs on a tube, let's say a json representation of the row. This was a killer feature for our use case. So we have an API which gets the rows, and places them on tube, this takes just a few milliseconds, so you could achieve fast response time.

On the other part, you have now a bunch of jobs on some tubes. You need an agent. An agent/consumer can reserve a job.

It helps you also with job management and retries: When a job is successfully processed, a consumer can delete the job from the tube. In the case of failure, the consumer can bury the job. This job will not be pushed back to the tube, but will be available for further inspection.

A consumer can release a job, Beanstalkd will push this job back in the tube, and make it available for another client.

Beanstalkd clients can be found in most common languages, a [web interface](https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console) can be useful for debugging.