# Is data appended to a table or overwrite it if the table has existed already when streaming data into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

When [streaming](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) data into a BigQuery table, I wonder if the default is to append the json data to a BigQuery table if the table has existed already? The api documentation for [`tabledata().insertAll()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll) is very brief and doesn't mention parameters like [`configuration.load.writeDisposition`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load) as in a load job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no multiple choices here, so there is no default and no overridden case. Don't forget that BigQuery is a [WORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many) technology (append-only by design). It looks for me, that you are not aware of this thing, as there is no option like `UPDATE`.

You just set the path parameters, the trio of project, dataset, table ID,
then set the existing schema as json and the rows, and it will append to the table.

To help ensure data consistency, you [can supply insertId](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataconsistency) for each inserted row. BigQuery remembers this ID for at least one minute. If you try to stream the same set of rows within that time period and the insertId property is set, BigQuery uses the insertId property to de-duplicate your data on a best effort basis.

In case of error you have a short error code that summarizes the error. For help on debugging the specific reason value you receive, see [troubleshooting errors](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors).

Also worth reading:

- [Bigquery internalError when streaming data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148567/bigquery-internalerror-when-streaming-data/27149336#27149336)

Comment: What would be the better option for adding data to a table in BigQuery on a daily basis, using post request or streaming? What's the trade off? Seems to me the major difference is the size of the data to be added. Btw, we try to avoid using Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: It's costs vs dev work vs availability. If you use streaming insert you have a cost, if you use batch load you pay the storage on cloud, although you can delete it. Certain project require immediate data, then you need streaming insert, but if you can do less inserts, but bigger than you go with the external file.